# Meep installation and run on Cygwin

Tags: meep

I needed to use Meep for one of my simulations and am trying to figure out how to do it. I installed Meep on Cygwin platform as detailed in this website:

http://nikodem.blogspot.com/2015/12/installing-meep-under-windows.html

After installation, I open the cygwin bash shell and type `meep`, which gives me the Meep prompt : `meep>`

But whenever I try to run some example files provided along with the installation and stored in `C:\meep\meep-1.3\examples\`, eg:

> meep> bend-flux.ctl

I get the same error :

> ERROR: Unbound variable: bend-flux.ctl
>   ABORT: (unbound-variable)

Any help to figure out how to run the .ctl files would be really helpful.